# How to host multiple services using one WcfFacility

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I'm trying to host multiple services using one `WcfFacility` and IIS, and I'm seeing some confusing results.

Here is my configuration:

```
        var baseUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped));

        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => { f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero; }).Register(
            Component.For<IAttributeService>()                  
                .ImplementedBy<AttributeService>()
                .AsWcfService(
                    new DefaultServiceModel()
                        .Hosted()                           
                        .AddEndpoints(
                            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<IAttributeService>().BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()).At("Soap11"),
                            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<IAttributeService>().BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("Soap12")
                        )
                .AddBaseAddresses(new Uri(baseUri, "AttributeService.svc"))                 
                ),                      
            Component.For<ISessionService>()
                .ImplementedBy<SessionService>()
                .AsWcfService(
                    new DefaultServiceModel()
                        .Hosted()                           
                        .AddEndpoints(
                            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<ISessionService>().BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()).At("Soap11"),
                            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<ISessionService>().BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("Soap12")
                        )
                .AddBaseAddresses(new Uri(baseUri, "SessionService.svc"))
                ),          
            Component.For<ISampleService>()
                .ImplementedBy<SampleService>()
                .AsWcfService(
                    new DefaultServiceModel()
                        .Hosted()
                        .AddEndpoints(
                            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<ISampleService>().BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()).At("Soap11"),
                            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<ISampleService>().BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("Soap12")
                        )
                .AddBaseAddresses(new Uri(baseUri, "SampleService.svc"))
                )
        );
```

When I go to use the WCF Test client to check on this, it seems as though the methods available under each service are a composite of that service and all the services that I mex'ed before that. Example:
[image: looking at a service in WCF Test Client]

Am I doing this wrong? You can't add the `WcfFacility` multiple times, and poking around on the internets, I can't seem to find an example where someone is hosting multiple services in one facility.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the methods available under each service are a composite of that service and all the services that I mex'ed before that". What I see from the test client is three different service contracts each exposing two endpoints on different bindings (basicHttp & wsHttp). This is exactly what you've configured in the WcfFacility. Why do you expect something different?

Comment: I've got three different services with two different endpoints each. I expect to see two endpoints under any given service.

Comment: Hi @tom.dietrich, I am trying to set up a similar thing, but with a generic service. Did you have to include the .svc file to be able to publish metadata? I cannot seem to get that working, but can if I create a service channel via the ChannelFactory?

Comment: If you're using castle.windsor's wcf facility, the inclusion of the argument 'Hosted' tells it that there is a svc file out there. So make sure you're not using that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figured it out. Previously, I was enabling HttpGet on MetaData using the following code:

```
var metadata = new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true };
container.Register(Component.For<IServiceBehavior>().Instance(metadata));
```

Which was following the code in [this github example](https://github.com/vcaraulean/WcfWithoutConfigFile/blob/master/WcfWithoutConfigFile.WebHost.Castle/Global.asax.cs).

It seems as though this approach causes the WcfFacility to share MetaData for all services on any get request.

The solution was simple. First, remove that stuff. Second, configure each service component in this manner

```
Component.For<IAttributeService>()                  
.ImplementedBy<AttributeService>()
.AsWcfService(
    new DefaultServiceModel()
        .Hosted()
        .PublishMetadata(x => x.EnableHttpGet())
        .AddBaseAddresses(new Uri(baseUri, "AttributeService.svc"))             
        .AddEndpoints(
            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<IAttributeService>().BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()).At("Soap11"),
            WcfEndpoint.ForContract<IAttributeService>().BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("Soap12")
        )                               
),
```

Specifically, the trick was to add this code **`.PublishMetadata(x => x.EnableHttpGet())`** in every component.

Now I'm seeing the expected behavior on each service.

[image: The expected behavior! Yay!]

Edit: Once I got it working, I went to work removing things that may or may not be required- I love convention over configuration. Here is the result, doesn't seem to be anything else to take away. The nice thing about this is that I can refactor further into a generic registration for all services, rather than needing one registration for each. Just sharing the goods.

```
        Component.For<IAttributeService>()
            .ImplementedBy<AttributeService>()
            .AsWcfService(
                new DefaultServiceModel()
                    .Hosted()
                    .PublishMetadata(x => x.EnableHttpGet())
                    .AddEndpoints(
                        WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()).At("Soap11"),
                        WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("Soap12")
                    )
        ),
```

And here's the generic registration.

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly()
.Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(StandardServiceAttribute)))
.WithService.Select((t, _) => t.GetInterfaces().Where(i => Attribute.IsDefined(i, typeof(ServiceContractAttribute),false)))
.Configure
(cr => 
    cr.AsWcfService(
        new DefaultServiceModel()
            .Hosted()
            .PublishMetadata(x => x.EnableHttpGet())
            .AddEndpoints(
                WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()).At("Soap11"),
                WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("Soap12")                       
            )
        )
)
```

Comment: To quote the fabio: Castle.Windsor is too sexy by far!

Comment: What does the At("Soap11") mean?

Comment: Figured it out. (it is the address the endpoint will be available from  baseuri+"/AttributeService.svc"+"/Soap11"  in pseudo code)

Comment: Where did the svc url registration go? Are you keeping those in web.config or is there some convention built in to WCF Facility?

Comment: It's been like 3 years, but if I remember correctly, the `.Hosted()` method tells the WCF Facility that there is an existing .svc file to use as the url base point, so adding the basepoint was not actually required.